# Forwarding requests in servlets

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, forward

so I'm trying to create a servlet which will handle all requests for the WSDL at the endpoint, and then send the WSDL (Right now its just a file on the disk, later, I'm planning to change that file somewhat based on the permissions of the client). The way I'm trying to implement this is by creating a WSDLHandlerServlet class that's mapped to /* in web.xml. The way I understand it - all requests should be intercepted by this.

Once passed to the servlet it checks basically if the URI with query string is - "/TestProject/pace/soap?wsdl" and if so sends back the WSDL. This part works fine when I open "localhost:8180/TestProject/pace/soap?wsdl" in the browser and it displays the correct WSDL.

If the request has no query string, then I forward it to the cxf servlet which is linked to my web service implementor.

However when I send a request from a client (SOAP request), I get -

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 200: OK
```

Also it is clearly not reaching the implementing class since if it did, there would be a log. I suspect I have most probably messed up the servlet mappings.

This is the WSDLHandler Servlet-

```
package servlets;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class WSDLHandlerServlet extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        // This is just a test.. anything without a query string will be sent to
        // cxf servlet... and any long request ending with ?wsdl will yield the
        // wsdl.. need to work on the design...never mind now it is time to
        // begin!!
        String query = new String();
        query = request.getQueryString();
        /*
         * File abc = new File("/home/aneeshb/testing.txt"); FileWriter fw = new
         * FileWriter(abc);
         * 
         * 
         * if(!query.isEmpty()){ fw.write(query); fw.close();}
         */String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
        File abc = new File("/home/aneeshb/testing.txt");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(abc);
        fw.write(requestURI);
        fw.append("1234");
        fw.append(query);
        fw.flush();

        if (query==null) {
            fw.append("2");
            fw.flush();
            RequestDispatcher dispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("/pace");
            fw.append("2");
            fw.flush();
            dispatch.forward(request, response);
            fw.append("2");
            fw.flush();
        }

        else if (requestURI.equals("/TestProject/pace/soap")
                && query.equals("wsdl")) {
            fw.append("This is in part1 ");
            fw.flush();
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.setContentType("text/xml");
            PrintWriter respWrite = response.getWriter();
            File wsdlFile = new File(
                    "/home/aneeshb/Workspaces/Project1/TestProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/wsdl/stock.wsdl");
            FileReader wsdlRead = new FileReader(wsdlFile);
            BufferedReader wsdlBuffRead = new BufferedReader(wsdlRead);
            int temp = 0;
            while ((temp = wsdlBuffRead.read()) != -1) {
                respWrite.write(temp);
            }
            respWrite.flush();
            wsdlBuffRead.close();
        }

        else {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }

    }

}
```

My web.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-insance"
    version="2.5"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee           http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>cxf</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <description>Apache CXF Endpoint</description>
        <display-name>cxf</display-name>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <description>WSDL Handler</description>
        <display-name>wsdlh</display-name>
        <servlet-name>wsdlh</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlets.WSDLHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/pace</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>wsdlh</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

And just for good measure-the cxf servlet config file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" xmlns:soap="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap" xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/soap.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd" xmlns:tns="http://impl/">
    <jaxws:server id="jaxwsService" serviceClass="impl.GatewayImplementor" address="/soap" >
        <jaxws:serviceBean>
            <bean class="impl.GatewayImplementor"/>
        </jaxws:serviceBean>
    </jaxws:server>
</beans>
```

Thanks, any help with what I am doing wrong or ideas on alternate solutions would be great!